# ¿Como iterar sobre una consulta y hacer un push con node js?

Tags: nodejs, mongoose

tengo una "tabla" ventas y otra usuarios, en la "tabla" ventas tengo 3 campos el id, me_id, sale_user_id, esta tabla "ventas" relaciona los usuarios a los que le he vendido y la "tabla" usuarios tiene los datos basicos (_id, nombre, apellido)...
En una `peticion` envio un `id`, lo primero que hago es obtener los `id's` de los usuarios que estan vinculados a mi `id (me_id)` en la tabla ventas y luego con los `id's (sale_user_id)` que me retorna los recorro dentro de un `for` para traer los datos reales del usuarios con otra consulta en la tabla usuarios....

**EL PROBLEMA**
Al momento de hacer console.log() dentro de la iteracion me muestra los datos que corresponden al id del usuario, el problema es que no me hace push a la variable y me retorna un dato vacio,he intentado con async/await y no me funciona, ¿en donde estare mal?

Agradezco el interes.

**CODIGO**

```
router.post('/getPurchases', async (req, res) => { 

  var usuarios = [];  

  await Sale.find({"me_id": req.body.id}, (err, docs) => { 

    for(let i in docs){    
      let res = User.findOne({"_id" : docs[i].sale_user_id}, async (err, data) => {
        console.log(data) // Me muestra 3 usuarios que estan asociados a ese id de venta mas no me hace push
        usuarios.push(data);
      });
    }  
  }  

  res.send(usuarios);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

1. No te va a servir usar async/await si usas mongoose con callbacks.
2. Falta un paréntesis que cierre `Sale.find`.
3. Estás haciendo shadowing de la variable `res` y eso puede tener efectos inesperados el día que refactorices.
4. No haces nada con el eventual error que viene en el callback
5. Un bucle for/in no es asíncrono. Tienes que usar for/of, lo cual viene muy bien porque `docs` es un array, no un objeto.

Si haces por ejemplo

```
for(let doc of docs){
   // doc es el documento mismo, no necesitas hacer docs[doc]
}
```

Tu código debiera ser algo como:

```
router.post('/getPurchases', async (req, res) => { 

    var usuarios = []; 
    try {
      let docs = await Sale.find({"me_id": req.body.id}); // sin callback

      for(let doc of docs){    // for of en vez de for in
        let data = await User.findOne({"_id" : doc.sale_user_id});
        usuarios.push(data);
      }
      res.send(data);
    }  catch (err) {
       res.send(err);
    }
});
```

Te preguntarás por qué funciona ahora el console.log. Es porque éste ocurre cuando se completa el `findOne`. Pero cuando haces await a algo que no es una promesa

```
await Sale.find({"me_id": req.body.id}, (err, docs) => {  })
```

El flujo sigue de largo. Es como decirle

```
 await function() { }();
```

Que es como

```
 await undefined
```

Se resuelve de inmediato aunque por dentro hay llamados anidados. Tu ruta devuelve un array vacío y *después* vez lo que llega a la consola, aunque sea cosa de microsegundos de demora.